# Armory "send" button is not reacting

Tags: armory

I am trying to send BTC with Armory. Everything works just fine until I have to hit the "send"-button. Then it just does nothing.

I have had this problem before (I had even posted it here) and solved it by clicking the same button a billion times. Now this isn't helping anymore. I am using 0.92-3 beta.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using [your old account?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/20766/deus-ex-machina)

Comment: what does armory's log file say?

Comment: @ Nick: Personal Confusion, nothing more I will check the logfile tonight. Thanks for now.